# Assumption of equipartion theorem in Langevin equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory, brownian-motion

To show Einstein's diffusion relation, one can develop the mean square displacement from the Langevin equation as shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem#Brownian_motion In this demonstration one uses the fact that the solute that is diffusing in a liquid is in thermal equilibrium with the liquid, and hence they share both the same temperature. Thus they use equipartion theorem to substitute some parts of the Langevin equation given the temperature of the fluid. I assume that the solute is just one more molecule of the system, and since its mass is much much higher than the molecules, its speed will be much lower because the energy a molecule has and this solute is the same. But now, the question that I have is related to the equipartion theorem. Wasn't this result only valid for a monoatomic ideal gas? How can you apply this to a liquid with a big solute inside it that is interacting with such amount of collisions with the molecules of the liquid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late, but this is an answer.

The equipartition theorem has a general validity, provided classical statistical mechanics can be applied. In the present context, it is a general result on the average value of $\langle p_i^2\rangle$ ($p_i$ being one component of the momentum of one particle) and does not depend on whether such a particle is an atom or a whole molecule in a one-component system or in a mixture and also does not depend on the thermodynamic phase.

Such independence on the system can be seen almost immediately by looking at the derivation of the result in the canonical ensemble (however the result is independent of the ensemble).

It is simply a matter of noticing that if the Hamiltonian has the form
$$
H(p_1,\dots,p_{3N},q_1,\dots,q_{3N})= \sum_{i=1}^{3N}\frac{p_i^2}{2m_i}+U(q_1,\dots,q_{3N})
$$
we have
$$
\langle p_i^2\rangle=\frac{1}{Z}\int{\mathrm d}\Gamma p_i^2 e^{-\beta H},\tag{1}
$$
where $Z$ is the canonical partition function, $\beta=\frac{1}{k_BT}$ and
${\mathrm d}\Gamma$ is the phase space volume measure of classical statistical mechanics.
Notice that the exponential (Boltzmann's factor) can be factorized into
$$ e^{-\beta H} = e^{-\beta \frac{p_i^2}{2m_i}} e^{\beta H'}, $$
where $H'$ does not depend on $p_i$. Therefore the explicit integral in $(1)$ and $Z$ factorize leaving
$$
\langle p_i^2\rangle=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p_i^2 e^{-\beta \frac{p_i^2}{2m_i}}}{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\beta \frac{p_i^2}{2m_i}}}.
$$
After a simple integration by parts, we get
$$
\langle p_i^2\rangle=\frac{m_i}{\beta}
$$
and finally $\langle \frac{p_i^2}{2m_i}\rangle=\frac{k_BT}{2}$.

As it is clear from the derivation, no assumption on the phase (solid, liquid, or gas) has been used.

Comment: Nice answer.   I'll take the opportunity to link my own answer (agreeing with yours) to a similar question over on [Chemistry.SE]:  [Does the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution apply to gases only?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34726/does-the-maxwell-boltzmann-distribution-apply-to-gases-only/)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by GiorgioP is excellent while concise. I would like to add that the application of equilibrium statistical mechanics implies the acknowledgement of ergodicity hypothesis. In the present case it means the equipartition theorem for the larger particles should only hold when these particles and the molecules of the liquid have interacted so much that ergodicity of the entire system is reached. That's why the solutions of Langevin equation in forms where the result of equipartition theorem is used only applies for infinite time. Indeed, using the equipartition theorem in the derivation only affects the infinite-time limit of the solution of Langevin equation. Practically, it is asymptotically valid for time scales much larger than $m/\gamma$, where $m$ is the mass of the particle and $\gamma$ is the drag coefficient. By time scale we mean the lag time between two successive records of the position and momentum of the particle during experimental observation. Therefore, although the Langevin equation predicts an non-equilibrium process, the use of equipartition theorem, which need ergodic hypothesis, does not violate the logic.