# Use equipatition theorem when studying Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, fluctuation-dissipation

Not a physicist so excuse my ignorance.

I am currently studying introductory topics on Brownian mechanics. Utilizing the Langevin equation for a Brownian particle submerged in a fluid with no external applied forces, we are able to show that

$$\langle u(t \rightarrow \infty)^2 \rangle=\frac{F_0}{2ζm}$$

where $F_0$ corresponds to the scale of the random forces, $ζ$ to the friction coefficient between the particle and the fluid, and $m$ to the mass of the particle.

Since the system reaches equilibrium as $t \rightarrow \infty$, it is proposed that the equipartition theorem can be used. So lets suppose for one degree of freedom of particle movement:

$$\langle u^2 \rangle=\frac{F_0}{2ζm}=\frac{k_BT}{m} \rightarrow F_0=2ζk_BT$$

So my question is: Is the usage of the equipartition theorem for a Brownian particle valid? As far as I can understand, the equipartition theorem stems from results regarding gas molecules.

Comment: Related: [Einstein relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_relation_(kinetic_theory)) (particularly the Stokes-Einstein equation.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks to be a dupe of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/542758/25301